# LINQ to Objects for POCO or generic classes

Tags: c#, linq, list, generics, poco

After doing research on [LINQ to DataSets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_DataSets), I remembered that my data resides in [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) classes and or Generic Lists of type <T> or Generic classes for a specific object.

With this information, if I want to use LINQ on those type of objects, I imagine I would use [LINQ to Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_Objects) and not LINQ to DataSets (even though a dataset is really just a class under the covers).

Am I correct in assuming this?

If so, does anyone have any links on how to use LINQ specifically with these kind of objects?

Comment: What is the source of your data? Is it a database? If it is, you should probably look for LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities. They would allow you create queries which would be translated into SQL statements, what is much more efficient then LINQ to Objects queries.

Comment: The data is already retrieved from a database using standard sql queries and placed in an object like a POCO Customer class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you download [LINQPad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINQPad). It's free without IntelliSense, but it is worth paying for it. It has a lot of LINQ samples that you can easily run without building a project.

Comment: I already have the full blown version of linqpad. However, if you check the above comment I made to Marcin, you'll see that the data has already been retrieved and is in a POCO class.

Comment: IN other words, what type of linq (linq to objects, linq to datasets) would I use for this type of scenario. I don't need linq to sql because the data has already been retrieved via t-sql into classes.

Comment: Yes I understood that but there are linq to objects examples in linqpad.  It's definitely not just limited to linq-to-sql.  The syntax is identical.  Instead of selecting from datacontext, you can select from collections